# CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy Memory Leak

Tags: asp.net, memory-leaks

I'm trying to locate a memory leak in our application.  Using DotProfiler, I can see that on various snapshots `CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy` count keeps increasing and never appears to drop.

[image]

I'm struggling to find what this event handler is associated with or what code might be causing this.  What typically would cause this to be leaky?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called when the UI controls are being loaded (the OnLoad method of the UI control) so that the callbacks can be managed.

You may want to check following points to focus on the memory leak search:

- how much UI controls your code is generating
- are their OnLoad events are really finalizing correctly (or there is something recursive ongoing)
- are there any async actions fired from the OnLoad activities and are they managed properly

An example of the stack trace where CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy is called, can give the idea:

```
...
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the clues - we do dynamically create web user controls from code behind , EG: `var icon = (ResponsiveImageFixedSize.ResponsiveImageFixedSize)MP.LoadControl("~/PageControls/ResponsiveImageFixedSize/ResponsiveImageFixedSize.ascx"); ... Placeholder.Controls.Add(icon);`.  These are not disposed, and are often nested in other controls.  Could these be one cause, and should they be used in a using block?

Comment: Worth mentioning is that most controls have a reference to the master page within them.  Wrapping the control load in a using block breaks the website as it no longer has the master page reference.

Comment: It definitely smells like the reason. If the master page keeps the reference the garbage collector will / should not release the resources. I would ask, if all those objects are really needed, can’t they be generated on demand basis. No end user can cope with that much of UI control, so maybe a UI/UX design revision can help streamline the control generation.

Comment: Thanks for comments, I'm changing the user controls to get the Master Page from `this.Page.Master` instead of passing it in, will do a memory profile and see if that's solved it.  This is for a pretty big website - each user control renders very specific but reused things so I don't think we're misusing it.

Comment: I think “reused” word is important in your comment. Do you mean “reusing the instance of an object” or do you mean “reusing the same object definition to generate new instances”? I was thinking it should be the second one which can be the reason of the leaks. (I think first does not allow you to reuse in multiple places).

Comment: And one more comment, I agree, it may sometimes be more logical to generate the objects upfront to avoid some back and forth.

Comment: Apologies, I mean we have lots of web user controls we use everywhere, but their intended life cycle is just for the page render.  EG, a "User Avatar" control which renders a user avatar.

Comment: Oh now I got it. Still the kept reference may be avoiding the garbage collector to release them

Comment: Have refactored out the master page property in all the web user controls, will publish changes at a quiet time of day to see if it has a positive impact.  Will jump for joy if it does!

Comment: Good luck. I hope it does.

Comment: Marking this as the right answer as `CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy` leaks are no longer happening!  Thank you!

Seems to be running just fine and garbage collecting properly - so cautiously am thinking this memory leak is now fixed.

Comment: I am very glad to hear that. Cheers!